# JQuery to help page act like a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something similar to [www.wanderfly.com](http://www.wanderfly.com) .
Basically the end goal is to have the divs in my page act like a checkbox, so at the end
when a submit button is clicked the user will be transferred to something like:

**mysite.co.uk/City=1|4|5|9**

So in this example the user clicked on divs number 1,4,5 & 9. if he would have clicked div
4 again then he would've been passed to:

**mysite.co.uk/City=1|5|9**

I hope i'm clear, please help me with a right direction on how to handle this and if JQuery has 
already a library for something of this sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').bind('click', function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});

$('#button').bind('click', function() {
    var newURL = 'http://mysite.co.uk/City=';
    $('div.selected').each(function() {
        newURL= newURL+$(this).attr('id')+'|';
    });
    alert(newURL);
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/YHuMT/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="option" value="1">Click me!</div>
<div class="option" value="2">Click me too!</div>
<div class="option" value="3">And me!</div>
<button id="submit">Submit!</button>

$(".option").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
    var q = "City=";
    $(".option.selected").each(function(i, el){
        q += $(el).attr("value")+"|";
    });
    q = q.slice(0, -1);
    window.location = "http://www.mysite.co.uk/?"+q;
});
```

Comment: But what happens if a user clicks the div twice (in order to disable it)?